# Next.js Per-Page Layouts or how to make 2 link 1 page/screen navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, next.js, next.js13

next.js i have this url: "http://localhost:3000/forum" and if user go "http://localhost:3000/forum/{postId}" i want to send user again "http://localhost:3000/forum"

i also used this (my folder structure is App. Not pages):
`import { useRouter } from 'next/navigaiton';`

and there is no problem with going to page. but i dont want to send user to new page. ı want to update the params while keeping the user on the same screen.

and i did this:

```
  // Function to handle selecting a topic
  const handleSelectTopic = (topicID: string) => {
    // Update the URL to include the selected topicID
    // router.replace(`/forum/${topicID}`);
    window.history.pushState({}, "", `/forum/${topicID}`)
    // window.history.pushState(null, 'test', `/forum/${topicID}`);
    // setName(`${topicID}`);
    // router.push({
    //   pathname: '/forum',
    //   query: {
    //     pageId: topicID // update the query param
    //   }
    // },
    //   undefined,
    //   { shallow: true },
    // )
  };
```

This is working for updateding params of url but if user have a link as that:   http://localhost:3000/forum/8e90eb70-83d3-11ee-a39e-06efd237be49

and when clicked on this, Its routing to not found page how can i directly send user to "http://localhost:3000/forum" path.

I have this resources:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/48110
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts
and i used this package: https://github.com/47ng/next-usequerystate

But i want that is there any easy way for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this problem in next.js with app directory. With creating 2 file.

as:

```
 - forum (folder)
    - page.tsx (file)
    - [slug] (folder)
       - page.tsx (file)
```

And dont forget these 2 page.tsx file are same but i just check is there any params on url:
this is forum > page.tsx file

```
"use client";

import { ForumLayout } from "@/components";
import StorageService from "@/utils/Storage";
import React from "react";

export default function Forum() {
  // const sessionToken = StorageService.getAuthToken();
  // const feed =  StorageService.getDiscoverFeed();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
         <ForumLayout />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

and this is forum > [slug] > page.tsx file:

```
"use client";

import { ForumLayout } from "@/components";
import { PostDetailModel } from "@/utils/models";
import React from "react";

export default function ForumTopic({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) {
    var topicId = params.slug;
    console.log("topicId", topicId);
    
    const { post } = PostDetailModel(topicId);
    console.log("post", post);
    
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {/* Forum topics accessed from the link */}
            <ForumLayout topic={post} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

i render it if there is any selected topic or not.
this page directory structure fix my problem.